# How do I set the close operation on a GLUT program written in C? (as in the red button in the top left corner to work)

Tags: c, macos, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm writing a really simple program using GLUT and C in XCode 4.2.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Program");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When the window opens up, I can't close it via the red button in the top left corner (Mac) because it is grayed out. If any Java programming I've done is a model, there should be some function that sets the close operation so that the red exit button works. I also can't seem to find the documentation for the most recent version of GLUT. Whenever I google it I seem to get OpenGL documentation, which makes me a little more confused then I was on the relationship between the two (I thought GLUT was a cross-platform interface to interact with OpenGL).

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?

Comment: I honestly don't know. As I understand, that stuff is included in the distributions of XCode and OpenGL is in the System Updates. So I am using whatever is packaged in with XCode 4.2 and Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Mac's windowing system to write a native Mac-like application (and you should - your users will thank you!), you should be using NSOpenGLView instead of GLUT. There's some good sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS, the window cannot be closed and the application has to be quit instead ([sources](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2%3a-Hello-World%3a-The-Slideshow.html) [here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=48177)).

Answer (score 2):

Using the GLUT bindings for python on OS X, I find passing an event handler to glutWMCloseFunc is enough to give an action (apparently this is deprecated in favour of glutCloseFunc, but not with my version).

Answer (score 1):

well, i encountered this problem now, and i use

```
Command + Q
```

to quit the process, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for the close button and it will appear:

```
void winCloseFunc()
{
    glutDestroyWindow(g_windowId);
    exit(0);
}

int main( ... )
{
    ...
    glutWMCloseFunc(winCloseFunc);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't work. It still creates the window with disabled button.